# How to use self trained model in Tensorflow for image classification

Tags: tensorflow

I used the following documentation to train my own model to classify flowers as described there:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception#how-to-train-from-scratch

```
bazel-bin/inception/flowers_train --batch_size=32 --train_dir=/tmp/flowers_train --data_dir=/tmp/flowers_data
```

I specified --max_steps=30 only to see if I can use the model as expected for classification afterwards.
After these training steps I get the following files:

```
model.ckpt-29.data-00000-of-00001
model.ckpt-29.index
model.ckpt-29.meta
```

Unfortunately I actually don't know how to use these three files for image classification. Is there any example showing the necessary steps?

Answer (score 0):

There's a section on how to evaluate (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception#how-to-evaluate).  It will use the saved model (those three files) to classify images and test it against the ground truth labels.  You can dig into the code (models/inception/inception/inception_eval.py) to see how it loads and does the raw inference.